How to pull docker images from ECR in Testcontainers when using Podman
Since switching to Podman from Docker for Mac, we can't pull images from ECR. Keep getting the error:
ContainerFetch Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=<imagename-from-ecr>
In spite of being able to perform podman pull <imagename-from-ecr> no problem.
I confirmed the auths are configured in  ~/.config/containers/auth.json
